# Why is the duration attribute in the python mouse module completely off?

Tags: python, mouse, duration

I am referring to python's `mouse` library. I used `mouse.move()` to emulate moving my mouse to the position `(0, 0)`. The function has a `duration`˙attribute, which takes an integer amount of seconds to simulate my mouse pointer "travelling" towards those coordinates on the screen.

```py
import mouse
import time

before = time.monotonic()

mouse.move(0, 0, duration=2)

after = time.monotonic()

print(f"that took {after - before}")
```

In this case, I set duration to be 2 seconds, but if we look at the output:
`that took 3.7649999998975545 seconds`.
I tried another case where i set the duration to be 5 seconds, then the output time was:
`that took 9.327999999979511 seconds`.

The interesting thing is, when I retry with the same duration amount, I get the same **wrong** duration (so in this case I rerun the `duration=5` multiple times, and got both times `9.327999999979511 seconds`).

Why is it so off?

[Link to the mouse library.](https://github.com/boppreh/mouse#api)

Answer (score 0):

The `mouse.move` [code](https://github.com/boppreh/mouse/blob/f344eaaaf4ce9d326126dfcff90cd6198f94ebef/mouse/__init__.py#L112) is extremely naive. Rather than actually checking elapsed time and compensating for inexact `sleep` durations, it just assumes all `sleep` durations are exact and that no time passes outside of `sleep` calls:

```
if duration:
    start_x = position_x
    start_y = position_y
    dx = x - start_x
    dy = y - start_y

    if dx == 0 and dy == 0:
        _time.sleep(duration)
    else:
        # 'steps_per_second' movements per second, default is 120.
        # Round and keep float to ensure float division in Python 2
        steps = max(1.0, float(int(duration * float(steps_per_second))))
        for i in range(int(steps)+1):
            move(start_x + dx*i/steps, start_y + dy*i/steps)
            _time.sleep(duration/steps)
```

Since `sleep` durations are not exact, this code ends up taking a lot longer than it's supposed to.

Comment: Tbh, understanding this code is a bit out of my league, but then I guess I should just deem it wrong? As in the duration function.